# Spark Scala - get number of unique values by keys

Tags: scala, unique, rdd

This is a question from a beginner. I have a text file containing computer login information. Once I filter bad records, and map to only the 2 elements I need, I get rdd that looks like:

```
 (user10,Server1)
 (user40,Server2)
 (user20,Server2)
 (user25,Server2)
 (user30,Server2)
 (user30,Server2)
 (user71,Server1)
 (user10,Server1)
```

I need to find for each server the count of unique users,  I would like to get something like:

`(server1,2)
 (server2,4)`

I need to stay at Rdd level; no data-frames yet, and I don't know how to proceed.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide a solution **easy to understand** for you.

```
  def logic(data: RDD[(String, String)]
           ): RDD[(String, Int)] = {
    data
      .map { case (user, server) =>
        (server, Set(user))
      }
      .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
      .map { case (server, userSet) =>
        (server, userSet.size)
      }
  }
```

**Set** data structure can be used as the tool to find unique users.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have reduced the *input text file* to following `RDD`

```
 (user10,Server1)
 (user40,Server2)
 (user20,Server2)
 (user25,Server2)
 (user30,Server2)
 (user30,Server2)
 (user71,Server1)
 (user10,Server1)
```

Final `RDD` that you require would be similar to `wordcount` examples thats abundant in the web but needs a little bit trick. You can do the following

```
val finalRdd = rdd.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).map{case(k,v) => k}.map(x => (x._2, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

`finalRdd` would be

```
(Server2,4)
(Server1,2)
```